# Rails 5 - conditional before_save callback on belongs_to existence when relation is optional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have 2 models:

```
Card belongs_to :template, optional: true
Template has_many :cards
```

I want to add callback to Card:

```
before_save :set_status, if: self.template.exists?
```

but that throws error that the Card class does not have method 'template'?

I also tried:

```
 before_save :set_status, if: self.attributes.has_key? "template_id"
```

and:

```
before_save :set_status, if: self.template.nil?
```

(this also gave `NoMethodError (undefined method`template' for #`))

and:

```
before_save :set_status, if: self.template.present?
```

So how can I check if Card has a template or not?

**EDIT**

This works, but WHY does this work and the above do not? It seems that self.template has to be inside a method call.

```
before_save :set_status, if: :template_exists?

def template_exists?
  return !self.template.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
before_save :set_status, if: :template_exists?

def template_exists?   
  return !self.template.nil? 
end
```

^ This method works because the callback needs code that it can execute at runtime. You can pass it a symbol or string that maps to the name of a method, or you can pass it a proc or lambda that it can execute at runtime. But if you pass it code like

```
before_save :set_status, if: self.template.nil?
```

then it will actually try to execute that code at the time when you are setting up the callback, not at the time when the callback is called. When you are setting up the callback, `self` refers to the class `Card` not the instance of the class.

Here's some documentation on [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks) if you want more detail.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation - the key sentence for me was "When you are setting up the callback, self refers to the class Card not the instance of the class"